# Make radio buttons

Tags: radio-button, form-api

Sorry for this question, but is it possible to make radio buttons instead of select list from this piece of code?

```
function _nodereview_form_review(&$form, $axis, $node) {
  static $options;
  if (!isset($options)) {
    $options = array(
    20 => -2,
    40 => -1,
    60 => 0,
    80 => 1,
    100 => 2,
    );
 }

$form['reviews'][$axis->aid] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => $axis->tag,
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
);

$form['reviews'][$axis->aid]['score'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Score'),
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => $node->reviews[$axis->aid]['score'] ? $node->reviews[$axis->aid]['score'] : 50,
  '#description' => $axis->description,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);


if (NODEREVIEW_FIVESTAR_ENABLE) {
  $form['reviews'][$axis->aid]['score']['#type'] = 'fivestar';
  $form['reviews'][$axis->aid]['score']['#stars'] = variable_get('nodereview_fivestar_stars', 5);
}

$form['reviews'][$axis->aid]['review'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Review'),
  '#default_value' => $node->reviews[$axis->aid]['review'],
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
}
```

I know that '#type' => 'select' should be '#type' => 'radio', but something else also should be changed. I don't know what exactly.

Any suggestions are gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, the #options will need to be converted to the value for each radio button. You'll also probably need to add labels for each button as well.

Comment: I'm trying to use 
  foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
  $form['reviews'][$axis->aid]['score'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#title' => $option,
    '#default_value' => $node->reviews[$axis->aid]['score'] ? $node->reviews[$axis->aid]['score'] : NULL,
  );
  }
but it's not working...